# Problems in pktgen build

Tags: dpdk

DPDK and PKTGEN version 20.07 , and have followed all commands in the install.md .

I get this warning which is being treated as an error

`

```
FAILED: lib/common/3d47a30@@common@sta/core_info.c.o
cc -Ilib/common/3d47a30@@common@sta -Ilib/common -I../lib/common -I/usr/local/include -fdiagnostics-color=always -pipe -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Wall -Winvalid-pch -Wextra -Wpedantic -Werror -O3 -march=native -mavx -mavx2 -DALLOW_EXPERIMENTAL_API -D_GNU_SOURCE -Wno-pedantic -Wno-format-truncation -fPIC -include rte_config.h -march=native -MD -MQ 'lib/common/3d47a30@@common@sta/core_info.c.o' -MF 'lib/common/3d47a30@@common@sta/core_info.c.o.d' -o 'lib/common/3d47a30@@common@sta/core_info.c.o' -c ../lib/common/core_info.c
In file included from ../lib/common/core_info.c:27:
../lib/common/core_info.h: In function ‘lcore_mask’:
../lib/common/core_info.h:29:11: error: implicit declaration of function ‘rte_get_main_lcore’; did you mean ‘rte_get_next_lcore’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   29 |     lid = rte_get_main_lcore();
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |           rte_get_next_lcore
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors

Compiling C object 'app/a172ced@@pktgen@exe/pktgen-arp.c.o'.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

`

Mentioned above.  I have also tried with 20.02 and the latest 22.11.

Comment: Please update DPDK version, Pktgen version (tar or github). Is dpdk installed by using `pkg-config --modversion libdpdk`, into the question

Comment: Do u mean i should try with DPDK 22.11? The command you have mentioned, is it to match the dpdk version with the pktgen version? I haven't used it before

Comment: The right way to build pktgen is following same order (year of release) of DPDK. That is if you have `pktgen-dpdk-pktgen-22.2.0.tar.gz` use at least dpdk `22.01` or higher. If you have pktgen ` pktgen-dpdk-pktgen-20.11.3.` use DPDK `20.11.1 or higher`

Comment: The PKTGEN version is 22.07.1 , so I have compiled DPDK version 22.07 as well but I still get the same errors

Comment: Setup a zoom or google meet with live debug. I am not clear what is problem your facing as I able to built sucessfully.

Comment: how can I contact you?

Comment: send gogole meet invite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on live debug and discussion, the solution to problem is suggested as

1. use dpdk [release download from here](http://core.dpdk.org/download/)
2. Download pktgen [dpdk hosted project link](https://git.dpdk.org/apps/pktgen-dpdk/refs/)

As mentioned in the comment, the thumb rule is

> The right way to build pktgen is following same order (year of release) of DPDK. That is if you have pktgen-dpdk-pktgen-22.2.0.tar.gz use at least dpdk 22.01 or higher. If you have pktgen  `pktgen-dpdk-pktgen-20.11.3.` use DPDK 20.11.1 or higher

Always use release version major number of pktgen and dpdk to be same. This has more chance of getting it to work.

Answer (score 0):

As hinted at in the other response by Vipin, the main thing here is to check that your libdpdk is actually the version you think it is.
After installing DPDK 20.11, run `pkg-config --modversion libdpdk` to make sure that it reports libdpdk as `20.11`. If it reports something older, you need to make sure DPDK 20.11 is overwriting `/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig` when it builds and thus reports `20.11` when running `pkg-config --modversion libdpdk`

`rte_get_master_lcore` was renamed to `rte_get_main_lcore` in 20.11 DPDK and thus any version of libdpdk older will result in the failure posted